# "Under no circumstances" and "as" usage

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would be most appreciative if someone could answer about this sentence. I found this sentence in an agreement letter.

> Under no circumstances shall the waiter look to the Client as his/her employer, or as a partner, agent, or principal.

When i search in Google, `Under no circumstances` means `never do like this` and `look to` means `to hope to get help`. If so, does this sentence mean the waiter should not expect to get any help from Client as his/her employer, or as a partner, agent, or principal?? I don't understand the usage of `as` in this sentence.

Comment: In this context "look to" means "consider".

Comment: If so, does the sentence mean the waiter doesn't have to consider the Client as his/her employer, or as a partner, agent, or principal??

Comment: My reading is that it means that the waiter can not consider the Client as his/her employer, etc. I think the intent of this is as a legal disclaimer stating that the waiter does not enjoy any of the rights, recourses, etc. that are inherent in an employer/employee relationship or any of the other types of relationships listed.

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by @AndySchweig as comments:

> In this context "look to" means "consider".

and

> My reading is that it means that the waiter can not consider the Client as his/her employer, etc. I think the intent of this is as a legal disclaimer stating that the waiter does not enjoy any of the rights, recourses, etc. that are inherent in an employer/employee relationship or any of the other types of relationships listed.